# Left-align doesn't work as I want it to

Tags: java, matrix

I feel like this is a question with an easy answer, but I can't seem to figure it out for some reason.

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

            switch (c) {
            case 'i': 
                System.out.printf("[%d]", val);
                break;
            case 'b': 
                System.out.printf("[x]");
                break;
            case 'w': 
                System.out.printf("[ ]");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.printf("[%c]", type);
                break;
            }
            System.out.printf("%-2s", "");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This is the code. I have a matrix and I want to print it out like a table. However, this code doesn't do that in a neat way.

Switching out `System.out.printf("%-2s", "");` for`System.out.print("\t");` works but the spacing between the rows are too wide.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, to start with - how wide *do* you want the column to be? Printing `%-2s` with an empty string as an argument will just *always* print 2 spaces, but you don't want your column to be 2 characters wide I assume.

Comment: I haven't decided on that yet, but if n is the maximum possible length of a string, then I would want a column width of  n+2. If that makes sense... But for now, let's assume that the total width of the column is going to be 5.

Comment: I meant 6 (edit time for last comment passed).

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution is to do a two-step formatting:

1. First, in your switch block, you assign the formatted text to a string
2. In your System.out.printf statement that creates the right column width, you use the formatted string from step 1 as the value.

So in your switch block:

```
formatted = String.format("[%d]", val);
```

And below:

```
System.out.printf("%-6s", formatted);
```

In your case, which is still quite simple, you can also incorporate the column width in your switch block:

```
System.out.printf("[%4d]", val); // 4 = 6 (column width) minus 2 for the brackets
// ...
System.out.printf("[x]   "); // add 3 spaces to the end
// etc.
```